# TIBCO BW - ERROR , Can not open Project (REST and JSON Plugin)

Tags: rest, tibco, tibco-business-works

Hi Tibco BW Community,

Please help on below issue:

**Verison**: Tibco BW 5.12
 
**OS**     : Windows 7

**Issue**: I installed Tibco BW **REST and JSON Plugin** 
"TIB_bwpluginrestjson_1.1.1_win_x86" and immediately after installation I am **NOT** able open 'New Empty Project' or even 'Existing Projects' (Tibco

**Error**: I get "Cant Find fs.vfilestore.creatingrepo.message" error. (Screenshot Below).

[image]

**Note 1**: I received windows "windows 7 program compatibility assistant" warning after installing REST and JSON plugin giving options " Microsoft compatibility assistant ca fix the program " or "the program is installed correctly". I clicked on "the program is installed correctly". ( I now believe I should have clicked on other option)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the rest json plug-in version?

Comment: can you past the entire stacktrace?

Answer (score 2):

The issue was solved after replacing the xbean.jar in plugins folder with the xbean.jar 2.6.0 version.

Comment: works for me too! version 5.14. I have removed  xbean.jar from C:\tibco\bw\plugins\lib\ and added xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar